# Swing Application on Win 8 Platform

Tags: java, swing

I have Swing Application which runs absolutely perfect on Windows XP but fails to give desired Look And Feel on Windows 8(Dimension of Frame and Dialog Changes).I googled a lot but no solution. Will I have to make some changes to my app before deploying on Win 8?

Comment: add your `local and feel` type name here.

Comment: use layout for your frames. Else it's look will change in another system..

Comment: there are four areas Font, Insets, JFrame.setSize - JFrames Borders height, used LayoutManager, point 1-3 are defined by current theme in Win8...., for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnabl, compilable

Answer (score 1):

use layouts for your `Jframe`.
If you use IDE for design means the look and feel will change in another system.
so use layout for your design.

check this link [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

You can use this layout in Windows XP then try it Windows8.
This looks Will not change.

Comment: Thanks @karthi for your response.  I already used Group Layout for all my frames and dialogues.I think I need to make some control panel changes in Win 8, because look of other programs(ex eclipse) also changes...